# Remounting system on android emulator lasts about 10 seconds and reverses until reboot

Tags: adb, android-emulator

Found something odd with the Android 6.0 on x86_64 emulator (and possibly others) system images... is it something I'm doing wrong?

When I remount /system and push stuff to it, it's giving me a chance to push stuff at first but then after about 10 seconds it remounts itself automatically read only and stops me remounting it read/write, and just gives me:

`# mount -orw,remount /system
mount: Read-only file system`

until a reboot.

What gives? Has anyone come up against this before and solved it?

It doesn't appear to be the wrong error and I'm out of disk space - it looks OK:

`/system                  1.2G   783.7M   456.2M   4096`

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I saw the exact same puzzling behavior. To remedy this, use the `-writable-system` option when you start the Android emulator.

eg:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator @<avd_device_name> -writable-system
```

Issuing `adb remount` afterward should then allow you to push to /system until you reboot or remount read-only again.